php artisan serve (Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?))
I recently installed Laravel Herd for my Laravel projects. However, I encountered some issues:
Nginx log error:
2024/06/05 22:20:17 [emerg] 8764#8936: bind() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)

When running the php artisan serve command, I get the following output:
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8001 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8002 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8003 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8004 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8005 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8006 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8007 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8008 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8009 (reason: ?)
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8010 (reason: ?)

Everything was working fine when I was using XAMPP and Composer, which I had installed manually.
However, after installing Laravel Herd for my Laravel projects, I encountered these issues. I have checked the ports.
PS C:\Windows\System32> for ($port = 8000; $port -le 8010; $port++) {
>>     $connections = Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort $port -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
>>     if ($connections) {
>>         Write-Output "Port $port is in use."
>>     } else {
>>         Write-Output "Port $port is free."
>>     }
>> }
>>
Port 8000 is free.
Port 8001 is free.
Port 8002 is free.
Port 8003 is free.
Port 8004 is free.
Port 8005 is free.
Port 8006 is free.
Port 8007 is free.
Port 8008 is free.
Port 8009 is free.
Port 8010 is free.

disabled and enable the firewall, check if my php.ini file is present(which it is) and I have also restarted my laptop

How is this problem related to Composer?

If you're using laravel hard in windows or any other server for development
This is will solve your issue
For getting php.ini file run this command for getting php.ini file if you don't know exact path of your ini file.
php --ini

This command will return the file location of php.ini 
It will look like this in the case of Windows:
Loaded Configuration File:

C:\Users\SVA\.config\herd\bin\php83\php.ini

Then edit variables_order this variable
variables_order = "GPCS"

After you have changed this now you need to restart your server or restart your pc.
Now you can run php artisan serve and this will be workable

This worked for me. Why doesn't Herd set this by default.

Change the default laravel serve port number if you can, like
php artisan serve --port=8008

or you can kill you can kill the process manually by running this command :
kill $(lsof -t -i:8000)

or 

fuser -n tcp -k 8000 (for linux based user)

Then run serve command :
php artisan serve

This will work sure.

If XAMPP is running, exit it. Uninstall XAMPP.
If you use Herd, you do not need to run php artisan serve.
The web server is started automatically by Herd.
See http://<your-project-name>.test
https://herd.laravel.com/docs/windows/1/getting-started/paths

I have the same problem!
I installed and used the tool "Herd" that Jeffry introduced us to in a Laracasts YouTube channel tutorial about Laravel 11 NEW tutorials. It's a very helpful tool for Laravel DEV, but after a while I stopped using it. However, my PHP artisan serve command stopped working and reported that port (8000-8010,9000...) don't work like:
Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?)

it is little bit confusing because Herd is not running ! :-|
I also try to change my PHP version to the latest and edit my php.ini file but it is not working!

and finally find the Problem is Herd and FIX it :
Uninstalling Herd

In Windows go use Win+R.
Type appwiz.cpl and hit enter.
Find Herd, select it and uninstall.
Close any open terminal and run cmd or PowerShell
go to laravel directory and finally php artisan serve works again !



another way to uninstall:
In case you want to uninstall Herd from your machine, perform the following steps:

Quit Herd by right-clicking on the icon in the menu bar and selecting "Quit".
Uninstall Herd via the Windows uninstaller.
Delete the Herd config directory at %USERPROFILE%.config\herd
Uninstall nvm by deleting the NVM_HOME and NVM_SYMLINK variables from your system environment variables
Delete the shortcut C:\Program Files\nodejs if it is still present


YES !
[PHP] [Herd] [Laravel] [Laravel-11]

Friends, I use Herd and Openserver, changes in environment variables helped me.
You need to make C:\Users<user_name>.config\herd\bin lower than PHP
screenshot

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In my case i was using docker for a long time. When i've back to the normal use i've to install php in my windows again. When a tried to open an old project i came across the same error. What i did to resolve was simple:

Go to the php install path, in my case is:
= C:\php


Search for the file php.ini-development and remove the end of the text "-development"
It will look like this:
= php.ini

Now you will be able to run php artisan serve

The error message Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?) indicates that the PHP built-in server is unable to bind to the specified address and port. This can happen for several reasons, including:
Port 8000 is already in use: Another process might be using port 8000.
Permission issues: There might be permission issues preventing the server from binding to the port.
Network issues: There might be network configuration issues or restrictions.
